# how to set default values for accounts payable and accounts receivable in openerp

Tags: odoo

I am new to OpenERP. I am using the Medical module. When registering a patient, accounts receivable and accounts payable are required fields. I have to tried to make them not to be required but openERP won't let me. The message I get tells me that I have to do so codewise from a custom stuff. What I want to do now is to set default values for them so that I don't have to be filling it each time I create a patient.

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: It seems you have created database without demo data. Is it?

Comment: Yes I created a database without demo data. I want to configure everything myself. It's part of my learning process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to configure your default accounting properties. From the [OpenERP Tutorial](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/1/1_3_Real_Case/1_3_Real_Case_db_setup.html#properties):

> You now define some default properties, so that you do not have to think about which account is used for which transaction every time you do something. The main new properties are the four that associate accounts payable and receivable to partners, and expenses and income to product categories.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create demo/default `ir.property` model records for payable and receivable type of account.

for reference, search for `Properties` in `account/demo/account_minimal.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Acivate the developer mode. Be on the page for entering accounts payable and receivable. Above the edit button you may see a selection box drop down list. Select set default. Enter the parameters you wanna make default.
If your are not solved still, please dont hesitate to ask.

Comment: please where is the page located?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to setting -> on the implementation square click 'invoicing' -> go to 'chart of accounts' page -> install the one of your country (or the generic one).

This should resolve the problem.

p.s. Just noticed now the post's date...